# Spring security 4.0.1 custom authentication filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am designing custom filters based on number of business requirements using spring security 4.0.1 and I came across the Standard Filter Aliases and Ordering in spring,

CHANNEL_FILTER
SECURITY_CONTEXT_FILTER 
CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER
LOGOUT_FILTER
X509_FILTER X509AuthenticationFilter
PRE_AUTH_FILTER....and so on

which are looking good for my requirements, but I didn't know where to use them and how to use them. Please don't tell me to refer the spring documentation, its just placed as it is. Anyone who can explain to me with example is appreciated.